# Multiple markers working on my local server but markers not working on my live site. http://www.sierracrestweb.com/dev/

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

Here is the code below, Perfectly display the purple icon on my local server but markers not shown on my website, I search on google and try alternate method but still facing this problem, I guess it is due to Multiple loading API Key errors, but if this How to resolve this error? because I already remove all the script but still face the problem.

```
<script>
var map;
var marker;
var infowindow;
var red_icon =  'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png' ;
var purple_icon =  'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/purple-dot.png';
    var locations = <?php get_all_locations() ?>;

    function initMap() {
    var america = {lat: 37.09024, lng: -95.712891};
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: america,
        zoom: 7
    });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

   var marker, i;

    var i ; 
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i] 
    [2]),
            icon : purple_icon,
            map: map


        });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
    }
 }

  <script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
  language=en&key=APIKEY&callback=initMap">
  </script>
```

Comment: Does the map load properly? Are there any error messages on the browser console?

Comment: Mao display properly, I'm using the billing API KEY, and working on my local server but not working on my live server.

Comment: @Joyson You check my live serve website on given above link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the marker creation is working on your local but not on server then it is probably not related to the code itself.

I think that the issue is with this line.

```
var locations = <?php get_all_locations() ?>;
```

Most likely this function is returning a blank array due to which no markers are plotted on the map.

Try printing out the value of the returned array in the console to ensure that you are indeed getting the correct location array.

```
var locations = <?php get_all_locations() ?>;
console.log(locations);
```

Comment: Joyson yes I got an empty array, So what should I do next?? Any solution for this. Thanks

Comment: Joyson you're a perfect person and give me the idea and I find the error, thank you Man, but sorry for that I didn't choose your answer correct because I put my answer so in future all others that face this problem could work for that, Big Thanks, Man.